# Typescript React generic function type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a case:

```
interface State {
   Mark: boolean;
   Jane: boolean;
}

React.Component<{}, State> {

   state = {
      Mark: false,
      Jane: false,
   };

   fn = (name: string) => () => {
      this.setState({ [name]: true });
                     ^^^^^^^^^^
   }

   render () {
      return
        ['Mark', 'Jane'].map((name) => <div onClick={this.fn(name)}>{name}</div>);

}
```

Im getting error:

```
Argument of type '{ [x: string]: boolean; }' is not assignable 
to parameter of type 'State | Pick<State, "Mark" | "Jane">
```

I could do two separate functions for it, but I want to keep it generic. How could I make it generic so the error goes off?

Comment: The `any` type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this is a limitation of the ts compiler itself. Check this issue for more on that: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/26635

Now to solve your problem you can use `setState` with a callback version. Like bellow:

```
interface State {
    Mark: boolean;
    Jane: boolean;
}

type StateKeys = keyof State

class Test extends React.Component <{}, State > {

    state = {
        Mark: false,
        Jane: false,
    };

    fn = (name: StateKeys) => () => {
        this.setState(prev => ({ ...prev, [name]: true }));
   }

   render() {
       return ['Mark', 'Jane'].map((name: StateKeys) => <div onClick={this.fn(name)}>{name}</div>);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, tried it but without destructuring state in callback function in setState :)

Comment: fn = (name: keyof State) => () => {
      this.setState({ [name]: true });
   } should work